# Java - How to limit array item output per line

Tags: java, arrays, printing

So I have an array of 50 items. I would like to output them to the console in the format of 10 rows of 5 items, like so:

```
array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4],
array[6], ..
```

And so on.
How would I go about limiting the output like this?

Comment: You will write a code that will iterate through the array, output its items, and insert a new line after each 5.

Comment: With some for-loops maybe? Or with if(index % 5 == 0) print("\n");? Show some code of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop inside a `while` loop, like so:

```
int currentIdx = 0;
final int numEntriesPerRow = 5;
while (currentIdx < array.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numEntriesPerRow && currentIdx < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[currentIdx] + " ");
        currentIdx++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: No delimiter between values is a very ... condensed ... output ;-) aah :-)

Comment: @Jan Haha yea, I just noticed that. Updated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void printArray(Object[] array, int column) {
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(String.valueOf(array[i]) + " ");
       if((i % column) == 0) System.out.println();
    }
}
```